# Question about a simple design problem

Tags: java, design

At work I stumbled uppon a method. It made a query, and returned a String based on the result of the query, such as de ID of a customer. If the query didn't return a single customer, it'd return a null. Otherwise, it'd return a String with the ID's of them. It looked like this:

```
String error = getOwners();
if (error != null) {
    throw new Exception("Can't delete, the flat is owned by: " + error);
}
...
```

Ignoring the fact that getCustomers() returns a null when it should instead return an empty String, two things are happening here. It checks if the flat is  owned by someone, and then returns them.
I think a more readable logic would be to do this:

```
if (isOwned) {
    throw new Exception("Can't delete, the flat is owned by: " + getOwners());
}
...
```

The problem is that the first way does with one query what I do with two queries to the database.
What would be a good solution involving good design and efficiency for this?

Comment: A good rule of thumb is to access the database the least number of times necessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you change the `getOwners` method? If so, I would change `getOwners` to return an `ArrayList`. That way you can you just check to see if the list is empty and if not just use the list. Like so.

```
public ArrayList<int> getOwners() {
    ArrayList<int> list = ArrayList<int>();
    // Magic...
    return list;
}

// Later...

ArrayList<int> owners = getOwners();
if (!owners.isEmpty()) {
    throw new Exception("Can't delete, the flat is owned by: " + owners.toString());
}
```

I think the above approach is much clearer than any of the other ways.